# php calculate time segment sizes

Tags: php, time

I need to implement a kind-of advanced time processing feature and I get lost in dozens of PHP's time functions. I've got a TimeUnit class that represents time unit, which is a tuple: from, to and period type, where period_type is month, week or day. Example timeunit is:
from: 1st January 2013, to: 28th February 2013, period type: month - which represents two months. 01.01.2013-28.02.2013-month is not the same as 01.01.2013-28.02.2013-day - the latter one is segmented by days and has 59 elements in fact (31 days + 28 days), whereas the former one has 2 elements (just two months).

I need to implement the following: I dump the TimeUnit into the day-scale period type (either from months or from weeks). I need to return sequence of segment sizes, which is a list of sizes. For example I've got 3 weeks TimeUnit and I dump it to days, so I expect to have 7,7,7. If I have 4 months (Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep) I'll get (30,31,31,30).

So far I'm using DateInterval, but it seems there'll be quite a lot of code (different for weeks and different for months) and maybe someone here has a better solution, maybe a built-in PHP function for that?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, this sounds like a job for the [`DateInterval`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) class. I'm not fully sure about your exact requirements (you should show some code), but if the `DateInterval` class will not do the job completely then you may extend or decorate it.

Comment: Yep, I'm looking for a wonderful PHP built-in function that could probably do the job for me, but you seem to say there's no such one, right?